# Flair English sentiment model download

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, nlp, flair

I'm trying to download the en-sentiment model using the following code:

```
clf = TextClassifier.load('en-sentiment')
```

but I'm getting the following SSL error:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='nlp.informatik.hu-berlin.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /resources/models/sentiment-curated-distilbert/sentiment-en-mix-distillbert_4.pt (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL] unknown error (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

I understand this is an issue with my firewall but I can't seem to get around it. I've tried installing openssl in my virtual env but this isn't working. I understand you can download the model manually but I can't find where to download them from.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Max retries exceeded with url` says it all. Are you sure you can ping the address: [nlp.informatik.hu-berlin.de](https://nlp.informatik.hu-berlin.de)?

Are you sure you can access the resource with web browser?

https://nlp.informatik.hu-berlin.de/resources/models/sentiment-curated-distilbert/sentiment-en-mix-distillbert_4.pt

Please check if you are behind a proxy or firewall and if the certificate of the page is valid. Once you can access with web browser, you are going to be able to run your code.